# can not install DjangoSEO with easy_install

Tags: python, django, windows, easy-install

it is first time I use easy_install on my Windows 7. I want to install DjangoSEO with it. But it shows an error. I have Python2.7 (32 bits) . Can anyone help me with it?

```
 C:\Users\hl>easy_install DjangoSEO
 Searching for DjangoSEO
 Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/DjangoSEO/
 Best match: DjangoSEO 1.0
 Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/DjangoSEO/DjangoSEO-1.0.ta
 .gz#md5=69cd65eb3a9d716b5ba067b1a4e63735
 Processing DjangoSEO-1.0.tar.gz
 Running DjangoSEO-1.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\hl\appdata\loca
 \temp\easy_install-nb1z4k\DjangoSEO-1.0\egg-dist-tmp-_nez8j
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1676, i
main

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1664, i
with_ei_usage

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1680, i
<lambda>

File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in
run

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 446, in
easy_install

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 476, in
install_item

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 655, in
install_eggs

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 932, in
build_and_install

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 921, in
run_setup

 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 26, in run_setup
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 66, in run
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 28, in <lambda>
 File "setup.py", line 35, in <module>
description="pip installs packages. Python packages. An easy_install replac
ment",
 File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 223, in __init__
 File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 287, in __init__
self.finalize_options()
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 256, in finalize_option

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1916, in load
  than any other pre-release tag.
 ImportError: <module 'setuptools.dist' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dist
 ibute-0.6-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.pyc'> has no 'check_packages' attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all setuptools files and easy_install files in sitepackages. then download distribute_setup.py from http://python-distribute.org/ run it with python, and  use pip to install djang-seo. It solved the problem